# ListIterator swap current and next

Tags: java, swap, listiterator

I need to swap node and node.getNext() in the ListIterator "nodeListIterator" and I've been trying for hours

```
 if (node instanceof LdcInsnNode && (node.getNext() instanceof FieldInsnNode && node.getNext().getOpcode() == Opcodes.GETSTATIC)
        && node.getNext().getNext().getOpcode() == Opcodes.IMUL) {
        // code
 }
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Can you actually include the code and describe the specific problems you're seeing?

Comment: @hooda The code is completely irrelevant, this is a question of algorithms. Its reaching the given if statement and the if statement is validating i just need to reorder the ListIterator.........

Comment: @JordFlo Please explain what your code is attempting to accomplish in terms of an algorithm, not in terms of coding. For example, you say you want to swap `node` and `node.getNext()`, but I'm not sure if you mean you want to swap the first and second nodes, or if you want to swap every other node, etc. That is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Mathew Cliatt I want node to have node.getNext()'s index in the list iterator and I want node.getNext() to have node's index in the list iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, its hacky but it works

```
final ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> nodeListIterator = methodNode.instructions.iterator();
while (nodeListIterator.hasNext()) {
    AbstractInsnNode node = nodeListIterator.next();
    if (node instanceof LdcInsnNode && (node.getNext() instanceof FieldInsnNode && node.getNext().getOpcode() == Opcodes.GETSTATIC)
            && node.getNext().getNext().getOpcode() == Opcodes.IMUL) {
        AbstractInsnNode temp1 = node;
        nodeListIterator.remove();
        node = nodeListIterator.next();
        AbstractInsnNode temp2 = node;
        nodeListIterator.remove();
        nodeListIterator.next();
        nodeListIterator.previous();
        nodeListIterator.add(temp1);
        nodeListIterator.previous();
        nodeListIterator.add(temp2);
        nodeListIterator.previous();
    }
}
```